# display event in calendar | codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

My code is work fine in add new event to sql database .

but Not display the event stored in sql inside the calendar.

I WANT TO DISPLAY THE EVENT INSIDE THE CALENDAR

> JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var myCalendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

      events: "<?php echo base_url('Shedule/getCalender/')?>",
       type: 'GET',
       defaultDate: '2018-09-28',
       selectable: true,
      selectHelper: true,
       select: function(start, end) {
       var title = prompt('Event Title:');
         if (title) {
       var eventData = {
       title: title,
       start: start.format(),
       end: end.format()
       };
       $.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url('Shedule/addToCalendar/')?>",
     type: 'POST',
    data: eventData,
    success: function(result) {

        myCalendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');

    },
```

> Controller

```
  function getCalender ()
  {

   $events=$this->Shedule_model->getCalender();
  echo json_encode($events);
```

> Model

```
  function getCalender ()
  {

       $this->db->select("*");  
       $this->db->from("tbl_schedule");  
      $query = $this->db->get();
      return $query->result(); 
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I SOLVED MY PROBLEM BY MY SELF

> MODEL

```
 $this->db->select("`startdate` AS `start`, `enddate` AS `end`, `visittype AS `title`");  
       $this->db->from("tbl_schedule");  
      $query = $this->db->get();
      return $query->result();
```

> AJAX - ADD EVENT - DISPLAY EVENT - REFRESH CALENDAR

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
    refresh_calendar();
       });
    function refresh_calendar() {
     var myCalendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
     right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
      },
    events: "<?php echo base_url('Shedule/getCalender/')?>",
     type: 'GET',
    defaultDate: '2018-09-28',
     selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    success: function(result){
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar(result);
        }
     select: function(start, end) {
      var title = prompt('Event Title:');
       if (title) {
         var eventData = {
          title: title,
          start: start.format(),
           end: end.format()
            };
            $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url('Shedule/test/')?>",
           type: 'POST',
           data: eventData,
            success: function(result) {
           myCalendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
             },
             error: function(xhr, status, msg) {
          alert(msg);
           }
         });
         }  
        }
        });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your controller must return a JSON output with a specific format. For example:

```
{
  events: [
    {
      title: 'Event1',
      start: '2011-04-04'
    },
    {
      title: 'Event2',
      start: '2011-05-05'
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: i make this for TEST before , and not work also .  $data = array
        (
           
                'id' => 1, 
                'title' => "nojoud",
                'start' => "2018-09-28",
                'end' => "2018-09-29",

        );
     
        echo json_encode($data);

Comment: You forgot the key "events" in your test.

Comment: plz . explan , where i have put the events key ??? in controller or where ? couse i am try to put it in contlorrer and JS . and not work